# Calculating time between stops on a round-trip commute

Tags: sql, hadoop, group-by, hive, hiveql

I'd like to track how long someone spends at each train station on a round-trip journey. Let's assume my location data is generated via infrequent pings, so someone could ping two times or five times when they're at a given station. Location data would look like the following:

```
+--------+---------+------------+----------+
| person | station | ping_start | ping_end |
+--------+---------+------------+----------+
|      1 | A       | 10:24      | 10:26    |
|      1 | A       | 10:27      | 10:30    |
|      1 | A       | 10:31      | 10:35    |
|      1 | B       | 10:50      | 11:02    |
|      1 | B       | 11:03      | 11:08    |
|      1 | C       | 11:15      | 11:24    |
|      1 | B       | 11:30      | 11:32    |
|      1 | B       | 11:33      | 11:35    |
|      1 | A       | 11:45      | 11:50    |
+--------+---------+------------+----------+
```

I need to identify what the earliest ping_start and ping_end is for each segment of the trip, so my output would be:

```
+--------+---------+------------+----------+
| person | station | ping_start | ping_end |
+--------+---------+------------+----------+
|      1 | A       | 10:24      | 10:35    |
|      1 | B       | 10:50      | 11:08    |
|      1 | C       | 11:15      | 11:24    |
|      1 | B       | 11:30      | 11:35    |
|      1 | A       | 11:45      | 11:50    |
+--------+---------+------------+----------+
```

Does anyone know how to do this? I think the right approach is one that uses functions such as `MAX(ping_end) OVER (PARTITION BY person, station)` but I'm lost on how to treat the two times Person 1 was at Station A (e.g. when they departed and returned back) separately.

I'm writing this in Hive but open to any insight on how this would generally be done in SQL. Python is not an option due to dataset size - this will be scaled across multiple riders, dates, and stations.

Answer (score 1):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem that is easily solved with `row_number()` and aggregation:

```
select person, station, min(ping_start), max(ping_end)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by person order by ping_start) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by person, station order by ping_start) as seqnum_s
      from t
     ) t
group by person, station, (seqnum - seqnum_s);
```

It is a little hard to explain exactly how this works.  If you run the subquery, you will see how the difference between the `row_number()`s is constant for adjacent rows at the same station.